# Find the angles of triangle $MNP$.

Tags: geometry

We construct right triangles $BCN$ and $ACP$ on sides $BC$ and $AC$ outside triangle $ABC$ That angles $N=P=90$ and $CAP=CBN=60$ If $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$ then find angles of triangle $MNP$.

**My attempt**:I solved a similar problem I don't remember but I thought I should add other midpoints of sides but I couldn't do anything with that.Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint 1: Let  $AB = c,$ $BC=a,$ and $CA=b$ and the angles $\gamma, \alpha, \beta$, respectively. Then using only theorem of cosine to show that $$MP^2=MN^2 = \dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{8}+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}S$$
and $$NP^2 = 3\Big(\dfrac{a^2+b^2+c^2}{8}+\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}S \Big)=3MP^2=3MN^2,$$ where $S$ is the area of $ABC.$

This easily implies that MNP is a $30 ^{\circ} -120^{\circ}-30^{\circ}$ triangle.

**Hint 2**: Here is a more "elegant" approach. Denote the midpoint of $BC$ as $T$. Then prove that the triangles $NTM$ and $NCP$ are similar by $SAS.$ This will immediately imply that $NTC$ and $NMP$ are similar. However, $NTC$ is already a $30 ^{\circ} -120^{\circ}-30^{\circ}$, so you are done.

Comment: We have $MN^2=\frac{a^2+c^2}{4}-\frac{ac.\cos (B+60)}{4}$ How do you continue?

Comment: expand the cosine using $\cos \beta = \dfrac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}$ and $S = \dfrac{1}{2}ac\sin\beta.$

Comment: But here we have $\cos (60+B)$?

Comment: that's why you *expand* that using sum of cosines formula.

Comment: @dezdichado--For $cos(60+B)$ does the sum of cosines formula give you $\frac{a*cos B}{2}-\frac{a\sqrt3sinB}{2}$? Using that, and substituting $\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}$ for $cosB$, and $\frac{2S}{ac}$ for $sinB$, I'm still not coming out with your result.

Comment: @EdwardPorcella no, $\cos(60^{\circ}+\beta) = \cos 60^{\circ}\cos\beta - \sin 60^{\circ}\sin\beta.$ I am not sure what incorrect formula you are using.

Comment: @dezdichado--I'm using the formula you cite. I've just put in $\frac{a}{2}$ for $cos60$ and $\frac{a\sqrt3}{2}$ for $sin60$.

Comment: @EdwardPorcella why?

Comment: @EdwardPorcella, no $\cos$ and $\sin$ of $60^{\circ}$ are constant numbers, independent of $a$.

Comment: @dezdichado--Right, correcting that mistake gets me to $MN^2=\frac{a^2+c^2}{4}-\frac{ac}{8}*\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}+\frac{ac\sqrt3}{8}*\frac{2S}{ac}=\frac{a^2+c^2}{4}-\frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{16}+\frac{\sqrt3}{4}*S=\frac{3a^2+3c^2+b^2}{16}+\frac{\sqrt3}{4}*S$, which is closer but not quite there yet. Still working on it.

Comment: @dezdichado--ok, first OP comment should be $MN^2=\frac{a^2+c^2}{4}-\frac{ac*cos(B+60)}{2}$. From there your result follows.